# struts2 session value not rendered in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2, session-variables

I ran into a strange problem while using the struts2 session in my jsp.
So, I do set the session attribute in my action class. But when I try an access the same in JSP.

For the first time when the JSP loads, it doesn't work.

But the strange thing in here is if I refresh the same page, my session value pops up in JSP and everything display properly.

Any ideas on what may cause this..

Following is the code base I use:

In Action class, I have implemeted SessionAware: 
    session.put("dataModel", dataModel);

I have the getter/setters for dataModel as well in the action class

On the JSP side..

I have a javascript function which gets called via onBodyLoad, this function just makes the ajax call to my action class:

```
function setDashboardData() 
{
// alert ("calling fun !! ");
$.ajax({

    url : "dataAction",
    type: 'post',

    data: {},

    success : function(result){

        if (result == "success") {
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("please-wait-msg").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("dashboard").style.display = "block";   

            }, 10000); 
            //alert(' HI Func completed successfully !! ');

            // do nothing
        }
        else {
            /*alert('Inside resetPassword error !!');*/
            window.location='errorPage';
        }

    },

}); 
}
```

I am using the iterator tag to render value.

```
<s:iterator value="#session.dataModel" var="dataModelElement">
<s:property value="#dataModelElement.startDate"></s:property>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Following the struts iterator I am using for reading this session variable                 <s:iterator value="#session.dataModel" var="dataModelElement">
    <s:property value="#dataModelElement.startDate"></s:property>
    </s:iterator>

Comment: Please do not put details about the question in comments, as they can be removed. Anything relevant to the question should be *in* the body of the question.